# concat two int values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, integer, concatenation

I have 7 integer values (with 3,1,3,4,4,5,4 digits respectively) and I have to concatenate them to a single integer (i.e a 24 digit no.) . I tried to do it like this

```
create or replace function gen_id(int,int,int,int,int,int,int) returns bigint as $$
declare
    id bigint;
begin
    id = $1 * 1000000000000000000000 + $2 * 100000000000000000000 + $3 * 100000000000000000 + $4 * 10000000000000 + $5 * 1000000000 + $6 * 10000 + $7;
    return id;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select * from gen_id(100,1,101,1000,1001,10001,1000);
```

But when I execute it I get error: bigint out of range . Is there any other better way to do it ?
thanks

Comment: By "concatenation", do you mean string concatenation (after casting appropriately)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST(num1 AS text)||CAST(num2 AS text)||... AS numeric(24,0))
```

If you happen to have your IDs in some table, then you can do:

```sql
SELECT CAST(string_agg(CAST(num AS text), '') AS numeric(24,0)) FROM srctab;
```

Comment: problem is, in my database the id is stored as numeric(24,0) so I cannot update the column with string value. I need numeric value .Is this possible ?

Comment: @KumarRajput, just cast the result back into `numeric(24,0)`. Updated.

Comment: +1. Also, as an FYI (since you're using PostgreSQL), you can do casting using the slightly more convenient `::` operator.  In other words, `CAST(num1 AS text)` is the same as `num1::text`.

Comment: @JackManey, true. I prefer to use `CAST()` on SO as it is a standard operator while `::` is a PostgreSQL specific one.

Comment: The second query is bound to fail without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

As I can concatenate a string to integer

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(ISNULL(MAX(usuarioid) + 1, 1), 6), ' ', '0') FROM usuarios
```

usuarioid is string + 1