# PostgreSQL concat an int value with a numeric field

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I would like to do something like :

```
update cli_pe set nm_cli_espace_client = 9 || nm_cli_espace_client
 where nm_cli_pe = 7006488
```

`nm_cli_espace_client` is `numeric(0,8).`

How to make it easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE cli_pe
   SET nm_cli_espace_client = '9' || CAST(nm_cli_espace_client AS text)
 WHERE nm_cli_pe = 7006488;
```

If you need a resulting number, then `CAST` back the result:

```
... SET nm_cli_espace_client =
      CAST('9' || CAST(nm_cli_espace_client AS text) AS integer)
```

Your question is identical to this one: [concat two int values in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197000/concat-two-int-values-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

Prefixing a digit onto a number can be done by textual concatenation, as @vyegorov has demonstrated, but it's also easily done as a mathematical operation.

**Edit**: Easily, but *really* not quickly in PostgreSQL. Even though this approach is *much* faster when programming in languages like C and Java for integer types, it seems to be quite a bit slower in SQL under PostgreSQL when working with an int, and *immensely* slower for `NUMERIC`. Probably function call overhead for ints, and the general slowness of numeric maths when working with numeric. In any case, you're better off concatenating as strings per @vyegorov's answer.

I'll preserve the rest of the answer for a laugh; it's a really good example of why you should test multiple approaches to a problem.

A mathematical approach is:

```
nm_cli_espace_client = 9*pow(10,1+floor(log(nm_cli_pe))) +  nm_cli_espace_client;
```

There's probably a smarter way than that. What it does is basically produces the power of 10 with one more digit than the number being added to and multiplies the input by it.

```
regress=# SELECT (pow(10,1+floor(log( 7006488 ))) * 9) + 7006488;
         ?column?          
---------------------------
 97006488.0000000000000000
(1 row)
```

I'd love to have the smarter way to do this mathematically pointed out to me; I'm sure there is one.

Anyhow, it turns out you don't want to do this in PostgreSQL. With integer types it's a bit slower:

```
regress=# explain analyze select ('9'||x::text)::int from testtab;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testtab  (cost=0.00..26925.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.026..293.120 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 319.920 ms
(2 rows)
```

vs

```
regress=# explain analyze select 9*pow(10,1+floor(log(x)))+x from testtab;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testtab  (cost=0.00..34425.00 rows=1000000 width=4) (actual time=0.053..443.134 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 470.587 ms
(2 rows)
```

With `NUMERIC` types the text approach doesn't change much:

```
regress=# explain analyze select ('9'||x::text)::int from testtab;
                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testtab  (cost=0.00..17467.69 rows=579675 width=32) (actual time=0.039..368.980 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 396.376 ms
(2 rows)
```

but the maths based approach is horrifyingly slow even if I convert the `NUMERIC` to `int` after taking the logarithm. Clearly taking the logarithm of a `NUMERIC` is slow - not surprising, but I didn't expect it to be *this* slow:

```
regress=# explain analyze select 9*pow(10,1+floor(log(x)::int))+x from testtab;


                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on testtab  (cost=0.00..18916.88 rows=579675 width=32) (actual time=0.253..86740.383 rows=1000000 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 86778.511 ms
(2 rows)
```

The short version: Do it by text concatenation. In (PostgreSQL) SQL the maths-based approach is more than 200 times slower for `NUMERIC`, and about 50% slower on integers. It's a handy trick for languages where integer maths is cheap and string manipulation / memory allocation is expensive, though.